# Need to generate random numbers from 100 to 500

Tags: c++, arrays, random, numbers

For my class assignment I have to generate 120 random numbers ranging from 100-500.  This is the code that I am using now.
Below is a cut and paste of the output: I was expecting numbers from the range of 100 to 500. I am unsure of what I'm doing wrong. I am not getting the desired results. How can I fix it to get number from 100-500?

ran -10 ran -9 ran -9 ran -8 ran -7 ran -6 ran -6 ran -5 ran -4 ran -4 ran -4 ran -2 ran -1 ran -1 ran 1 ran 1 ran 2 ran 3 ran 3 ran 4 ran 4 ran 4 ran 5 ran 6 ran 6 ran 6 ran 7 ran 7 ran 8 ran 8 ran 9 ran 9 ran 10 ran 10 ran 10 ran 11

```
void create_random_numbers(int ran[], int x) 
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);

    srand(seed);
    int random_integer;
    for (int index = 0; index<400; index++)
    {

    //  cout << random_integer << endl<<endl;
        ran[index] =  (rand()%500)+100;

        cout << "ran "<< ran[index] << endl << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the question?

Comment: Below is a cut and paste of the output: I was expecting numbers from the range of 100 to 500. I am unsure of what I'm doing wrong. I am not getting the desired results. ran   -10
ran   -9
ran   -9
ran   -8
ran   -7
ran   -6
ran   -6
ran   -5
ran   -4
ran   -4
ran   -4
ran   -2
ran   -1
ran   -1
ran   1
ran   1
ran   2
ran   3
ran   3
ran   4
ran   4
ran   4
ran   5
ran   6
ran   6
ran   6
ran   7
ran   7
ran   8
ran   8
ran   9
ran   9
ran   10
ran   10
ran   10
ran   11

Comment: @jess You havent asked a question yet. Please edit the post accordingly. (If you want to display some output, update your post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand() % 500` yields values in the range `[ 0...499 ]` inclusive, so `100 + [ 0 ... 499 ]` yields values `[ 100... 599 ]` inclusive. You need `rand() % 400 + 100`.

Check out the corrected code below:

```
void create_random_numbers(int ran[]) 
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);

    srand(seed);
    int random_integer;
    for (int index = 0; index < 120; index++)
    {
        ran[index] =  (rand() % 400) + 100;
        cout << index << " : " << ran[index] << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Check the demo I have made: [Demo](https://eval.in/834186)

Comment: Wow, that was quick. And it works! Thank you so much. I have been working on this since yesterday and wrote it like that on my first attempt but obviously my syntax must have been wrong.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The other way is to use uniform int distribution
Produces random integer values i, uniformly distributed on the closed interval [a, b], that is, distributed according to the discrete probability

```
function
P(i|a,b) = 1/(b − a + 1)
.
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 120> numbers;
    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the 
                            //random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded 
                            // with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(100, 500);

    for (int n = 0; n < 120; ++n)
        //Use dis to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen 
        //into an int in [100, 500]
        numbers[n] = dis(gen);

    for (auto i : numbers) {
        std::cout << ' ' << i;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did use the uniform int distribution method before posting my question, and it did work.  However i could not figure out a way to get the generated values into my array.  I tried std:: myarray[] << dis(gen) <<; but was getting garbage.  How would I be able to capture the generated values? It would be good to know for future use.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.